# AQL Optimization - traversal by month

Tags: query-optimization, graph-databases, arangodb, aql

In ArangoDB, I have a graph which contains messages for profiles. For reporting purposes, I need to aggregate the number of messages for specific categories of message from each month for the last 12 months.

The date and category of each message are on every edge between the profile and the message.

Currently, I have:

```
for mo in 0..11
    let month = DATE_MONTH(DATE_SUBTRACT(DATE_NOW(),mo,"month"))
    let msgCount = count(
        for v, e in outbound "profileId" graph 'MyGraph'
            filter e.category == "myCategory" && DATE_MONTH(e.date) == month
            return 1
        )
    return {month: month, msgCount: msgCount}
```

This query executes in over one second, which is a bit slow for the purposes of this webapp, as I need to create and visualize this report for several categories.

Is there any optimization that could produce the same results faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Analysing the query

Using `db._explain()` shows the following:

```
Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType            Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode          1   * ROOT
  2   CalculationNode        1     - LET #7 = 0 .. 11   /* range */   /* simple expression */
  3   EnumerateListNode     12     - FOR mo IN #7   /* list iteration */
  4   CalculationNode       12       - LET month = DATE_MONTH(DATE_SUBTRACT(DATE_NOW(), mo, "month"))   /* v8 expression */
 11   SubqueryNode          12       - LET #4 = ...   /* subquery */
  5   SingletonNode          1         * ROOT
  9   CalculationNode        1           - LET #11 = 1   /* json expression */   /* const assignment */
  6   TraversalNode          1           - FOR v  /* vertex */, e  /* edge */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND 'profileId' /* startnode */  GRAPH 'MyGraph'
  7   CalculationNode        1           - LET #9 = ((e.`category` == "myCategory") && (DATE_MONTH(e.`date`) == month))   /* v8 expression */
  8   FilterNode             1           - FILTER #9
 10   ReturnNode             1           - RETURN #11
 13   CalculationNode       12       - LET #13 = { "month" : month, "msgCount" : COUNT(#4) }   /* simple expression */
 14   ReturnNode            12       - RETURN #13

Indexes used:
 none

Traversals on graphs:
 Id   Depth   Vertex collections   Edge collections   Filter conditions
  6   1..1    persons              knows              

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   remove-unnecessary-calculations
```

which can tell us the following:

- in the traversal we use V8 expressions, which is expensive.
- Since you're executing a complex filter expression, this can't be executed inside of the traverser - thus filtering is applied *after* the traversal was done.

### What you could do to improve the situation

You should find a way to move the complex calculations out of the iteration. 
While working with the `DATE_*` functions may be convenient, its not fast. You should calculate the strings YEAR:MONTH you want to filter for in advance, and then inside the the query do range comparison on the calculated strings:

```
FILTER e.date > '2016:04:' && e.date < '2016:05:'
```

---

#### Nate's implementation:

```
for mo in 0..11
    let month = date_subtract(concat(left(date_iso8601(date_now()),7),'-01T00:00:00.000Z'), mo, "month")
    let nextMonth = date_subtract(concat(left(date_iso8601(date_now()),7),'-01T00:00:00.000Z'), mo-1, "month")
    let monthNumber = date_month(month)
    let msgCount = count(
        for v, e in outbound "profileId" graph "MyGraph"
            filter e.category == 'myCategory' && e.date > month && e.date < nextMonth
            return 1
            )
    return {month: monthNumber, msgCount: msgCount}
```

This significantly speeds up the query (5x faster)!

Comment: Thanks! How can I turn a date into the YEAR:MONTH format you're describing?

Comment: looks good, another step could be to call date_now() just once before the loop.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much

Comment: simplified the example and added it here: https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/AQL/ExecutionAndPerformance/Optimizer.html#things-to-consider-for-optimizing-queries